# using one Auto email vba code that allows two cells to be double clicked and email out different ranges

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I am creating a spreadsheet for a warehouse to log problems with items 
   they receive. The warehouse staff will input the following ' criteria for 
   email' into each cell

A IS Reference number,
   C IS Part number,
   G IS Order number,
   N IS Issue with Part,
   R IS their email address,
   T IS Expediter email address,

Now I have made column U the cells that when the warehouse staff double 
   click, it brings up an email with the address in T and the subject of 
   A,C,G. The body of the text then includes a prompt for them to look at 
   the spreadsheet.

I want to be able to then make the column X do the same double click 
   function, but instead of emailing the same message as when you double 
   click column U, the expediters get a different address (from column R) 
   and a different subject and body to tell the warehouse staff they have 
   solved the issue.

I have written the code to allow column U to be double clicked and the 
   email box will appear, and it works amazingly! But i am stuck on how to 
   do the same for column X. I have tried copying and pasting the original 
   code underneath itself and changing the parameters to suit column X, but 
   excel VBA seems to treat it as if the code wasn't there?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, _
Cancel As Boolean)

Dim sRef        As String
Dim sMat        As String
Dim sIssue      As String
Dim sMeYou      As String
Dim sTo         As String
Dim sBody       As String
Dim sOrder      As String
Dim sSend       As String
Dim bSucces     As Boolean


On Error GoTo Err_Mail


If Not Intersect(Target, Range("U:U,X:X")) Is Nothing Then
    With Target

        sRef = .Offset(0, -20).Value
        sMat = .Offset(0, -17).Value
        sIssue = .Offset(0, -7).Value
        sMeYou = .Offset(0, -1).Value
        sTo = .Offset(0, -1).Value
        sSend = .offset(0,-3).value
        sOrder = .Offset(0, -14).Value


    End With


    Cancel = True
Else

    Cancel = False
    Exit Sub
End If


If sMeYou = "expediteremail@warehouse.com" Then
    bSucces = CreateMailItem(sTo, "Gareth," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "A 
new part has been added to the Plant 2200 Parts Register." & vbNewLine & 
vbNewLine & "Please open up the workbook to review." & vbNewLine & 
vbNewLine & "Issue relates to", sOrder, sIssue, _
    sRef, sMat, 2, False)

ElseIf sMeYou = "expediteremail2@warehouse.com" Then
    bSucces = CreateMailItem(sTo, "Gail," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "A 
new part has been added to the Plant 2200 Parts Register." & vbNewLine & 
vbNewLine & "Please open up the workbook to review." & vbNewLine & 
vbNewLine & "Issue relates to", sOrder, sIssue, _
    sRef, sMat, 2, False)

ElseIf sSend = "harrywood@siemens.com" Then
    bSucces = CreateMailItem(sSend, "Team please look at this", sOrder, sIssue, sRef, sMat, 2, False)



End If

If bSucces Then
    Target.Offset(0, 26).Value = Now()
Else
    MsgBox "Please fill in all Part details before sending email"
End If

Exit Sub

Err_Mail:
 MsgBox "Sorry there has been an error, please contact Harry Wood 
(Quality)"
End Sub

Public Function CreateMailItem(sTo As String, _
sBody As String, _
sOrder As String, _
sIssue As String, _
sRef As String, _
sMat As String, _
iImportance As Integer, _
bReceipt As Boolean) As Boolean
Dim oOutlookApp  As Object
Dim oOutlookMail As Object
CreateMailItem = False


On Error Resume Next

Set oOutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")


If Err <> 0 Then

    Set oOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

End If

If Not oOutlookApp Is Nothing Then
    Set oOutlookMail = oOutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    If Not oOutlookMail Is Nothing Then
        With oOutlookMail

            .To = sTo

            .Subject = "Ref: " & sRef & "            Part Number: " & 
             sMat & "       Order Number: " & sOrder

            .Body = sBody & vbCr & sIssue

            .Importance = iImportance

            .ReadReceiptRequested = bReceipt

            .Display
            CreateMailItem = True
        End With
    End If
End If


Set oOutlookMail = Nothing
Set oOutlookApp = Nothing
End Function
```

would copying this code again and changing the parameters actually work 
   or do I need to do something else? I am now stuck in my own limitations 
   of vba knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
If Target.Column = 21 Then
```

To:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("U:U,X:X")) Is Nothing Then
```

Comment: Zac,  Thank you, this does work in the sense that it now recognises column U as part of the code, but when i double click I instead get my error MsgBox that i put in the code. I edited my code to include another ElseIf but i think i am contradicting the code with it.

Comment: I have updated the code to show your suggestion implemented and the other ElseIf included.

Comment: Can you comment out your **On Error...** code and step through it to find out the exact error message you are getting